# ionic 4 and --ion-font-family

Tags: fonts, ionic4

I want to add a new font to ionic 4 but I have a strange problem with --ion-font-family.

- Steps:
- 1: I dowloaded and set my custom font Roboto-Light in the assets/font folder
- 2: I updated variables.css with code below

  @font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Light';
  src: url('../assets/font/Roboto-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  }

  --ion-font-family: "Roboto" , "Helvetica-Neue", "sans-serif", "Roboto-Light" !important;

I used google inspector to discover what ionic fonts are used by default and it was "Roboto" , "Helvetica-Neue", "sans-serif".
Ok.
Now the font-family use a fallback strategy.
That is to say, it try the first, if the browser does not support, it try the next and so on.

So now, my problem:
If a had "Roboto-Light" at the end of --ion-font-family, it should not be taken at the primary font !
And it is the case ...

I really don't understand and any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the complete solution but you have a mistake in your css:

```
--ion-font-family: "Roboto" , "Helvetica-Neue", "sans-serif", "Roboto-Light" !important;
```

The *generic-family* should always go last:

```
--ion-font-family: "Roboto" , "Helvetica-Neue", "Roboto-Light", sans-serif !important;
```